# What does the "demands " mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I want to use particular case studies **to bring out the very different demands that circumstances make on the practice of diplomats.**
>   I also want to give some sense of the way in which skilful diplomacy, as well as rashness, excessive caution, and clumsiness, can have important ramifications for the fate of nations.

What is the meaning of the sentence in bold? I think there is not any relation between the meaning of the words.

Comment: Try to group it as [ to bring out ] [ the very different demands ] [ that circumstances make ] [ on the practice of diplomats ]. Better? Still can't make sense of it? Which part that is still confusing?

Comment: I did it already, but i cant find clear meaning of them, can you say them in other wprds?

Comment: Which parts specifically that you can't understand? -- I have a hunch that your problem is more fundamental and more related to reading comprehension and sentence structures in general.

Comment: I dont understand al of the bolded text, say it in simple English.

Comment: can you say bolded text in simple other words?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use particular case studies **to bring out the very different demands that circumstances make on the practice of diplomats**.

Let's try to read it chunk by chunk:

> *I want to use particular case studies*
>   - Okay, but why?
>
> *to bring out*
>   - Great! You want to use those studies to [bring out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bring-out) something. What is that "something"?
>
> *the very different demands*
>   - Okay, so it's about the (very different) demands. What are these demands?
>
> *that circumstances make*
>   *on the practice of diplomats.*
>   - So, it's about the demands that circumstances make, and it's on the practice of diplomats. Got it!

Answer (score 0):

> to bring out - to demonstrate
>
> the very different demands - the needs of different
>
> that circumstances make on - situations that affect
>
> the practice of diplomats - what diplomats do

Comment: You mean: "to demonstrate the needs of different situations that affect what diplomats do" , then, what do You mean by " needs of different situations" ? plz clarify it. do You mean: "action that have done in different situations" ?

Comment: "what diplomats need to do in different situations"